# Looking to avoid ViewBag usage in MVC 5 - suggestions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have been googling how to remove any and all usage of ViewBags in favour of something more elegant and effective. Unfortunately virtually all of the information I have come across is for prior versions of MVC, and I have yet to find something that both works and is really effective.

One of my primary objective is to be able to populate both the page and the layout at the same time, so that I can add a page title to both the `<h2>` as well as the `<title>`. I also want to be able to, if needed, to supply the first paragraph of the body content, which is drawn from the database as a separate column, to the meta-description (this is a special case where all first paragraphs are their own separate entry in the row in the db, purely for the purpose of also acting as the meta-description).

I have [run across something that I believe will meet my needs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/253419/Getting-information-into-the-Layout-without-using), but I cannot seem to properly implement the fifth code block:

> Now create the view base class. You need to create two versions to
>   have support for typed views.
>
> ```
> public class ViewBaseWithLayoutModel : WebViewPage{
>   public LayoutViewModel LayoutModel { 
>     get { return (LayoutViewModel)ViewBag.LayoutModel; }
>   }
> }
>
> public class ViewBaseWithLayoutModel<T> : WebViewPage<T>{
>   public LayoutViewModel LayoutModel {
>     get { return (LayoutViewModel)ViewBag.LayoutModel; } 
>   }
> }
> ```

Specifically, it is the “create the view base class” that has me tied up in knots -- are they talking about an entirely new section in the project, similar to the Views, Controllers, Models, Extensions, Validators, etc., such that the namespace would be `namespace Project.ViewBase {`?

And if I can put the fifth code block straight beside another controller like BaseController (inside the `Project.Controllers` namespace but below the BaseController class in that file), why do both classes throw the errors,

```
'ViewBaseWithLayoutModel' does not implement inherited abstract member 'WebPageExecutingBase.Execute()'
```

As well, the sixth code block references

```
<pages pageBaseType="Namespace.To.ViewBaseWithLayoutModel">
```

So in the above case would it be 'Project.Controllers.ViewBaseWithLayout'?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although `ViewBag` is generally frowned upon, I have no problem using it for layout title and meta tags. Its convenience and simplicity far outweigh any custom default page model that post is trying to build in order to avoid the dynamic store (which still uses `ViewBag` internally!?!). There are easier ways, in my opinion, such a not-required sections and child actions. Forcing a default page model also makes all your views less flexible and eventually you end up with a fat BasePageModel with lots of fields not all your views may need but are forced to consider.

Comment: **ViewBag** is not evil. Passing ViewBag to Layout is never been an issue unless someone start treating ViewBag as Model. I have seen MVC sites with few hundreds to few thousands views with ViewBag. No wonder the article doesn't have any votes.

Comment: Never said that `ViewBag` is evil, I just want to move away from it for items that are going to be required on every single page. One-off usages are still perfectly fine in my book, I just don’t want to rely too heavily on it on elements that will be receiving content from any number of pages (like the meta descriptions and page titles).